# What are the important things to consider when moving with dogs to a country with cold weather?

Tags: dogs, house-moving

I have lived in a warm country all my life and had my pets here. I currently have 2 pomeranians (5yo, 4kg and 4yo, 6kg).
By warm I mean:
In summer, around 30 degrees Celsius, up to 40.
In winter, around 10 degrees, minimum of 5, no snow, usually sunny sometimes with some rain. No snow at all.

Now I am moving to Stockholm, with its harsh (to my standards) winters and I have no idea how to deal with winter.

They will be inside during the vast majority of their days, but **what are the most important things to have (I saw some dogs wearing boots during my research), notice and do so my dogs have a comfortable winter while still playing outside and having their daily walks? How long can we take them for a walk in cold days? (can we take them to a walk around the city center, for instance?)**

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! The boots I assume are mostly to prevent the paws from getting in touch with the salt used in urban areas for melting snow and ice on ways and lanes. I assume the most you need to think about will be the difference in temperature between the living room and outside. For your dogs it would be like staying inside and outside in the same coat. Depending of the fur they need to "take off their coat" inside, or to "add a coat" outside. And also you should not only think about temperature, but also about wet conditions. Cold AND wet is much more uncomfortable than really cold&dry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pomeranians have long fur, so they aren't *quite* as vulnerable to cold as other short haired breeds. Short walks or play times of 10 - 20 minutes at a time in temperatures around 0°C shouldn't be too bad for them in my opinion. Temperatures below -5°C  do need some acclimatization or the protection of a coat and you shouldn't keep your dogs outside for too long (maybe while shopping in the city center). You should watch out for shivering or a crooked back (the back is pulled up in an arc to protect the belly from the cold) and go back inside when you start seeing any of that. After a period of acclimatization they should be able to stay outside comfortably far longer.

As Allerleirauh mentioned in the comments, moisture is more of a problem than low temperatures alone. If your dogs aren't used to rainy weather, their coats soak up more water and stay wet for longer. However, the more they get used to regular rain, the more oily their coat becomes to protect them. Humans usually don't like that because the coat feels and smells "dirty". So I suggest getting your dogs used to wearing rain coats.

One big risk is a very sudden and intense shedding of hair that can be caused by the stress of moving, a sudden and drastic change in temperatures or a significant change in day length ([source](https://topdoghealth.com/what-to-do-when-dog-is-shedding-too-much/)). That can quickly matt the fur which will require shearing the dog, which makes the cold even worse for it. So you must brush your dogs more often than usual for the first 2 - 3 months after the move. If you notice that they shed so much you cannot keep the fur untangled, take them to a groomer before the fur mats.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding temperature, you should do a slow transition. If you move during summer, then just do business as normal.

If you move during cold temperatures, then do NOT take your dogs out, if possible. Start taking them out when the higher temperatures come back, usually in the spring. Continue as normal. Going through the autumn will prepare them for the colder temperatures.

Alternative: IF you have a balcony or shed or something, with colder, but not-that-cold temperatures, you can allow the dogs to spend time there. Maybe you can "adjust" the temperature in that area, so you can help hem transition faster.

Please be aware that faster is not necessarily better, it can actually be worse.